# possible paths to increase bench press from 140kg (308 lbs) to 160 kg (352) - for 1o reps

Tags: strength, strength-training, training, bench-press, reps

I really liked this question below and its answer.

[Improving my Bench Press - what muscles are used during what phase?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2206/improving-my-bench-press-what-muscles-are-used-during-what-phase?rq=1)

I am looking for to increase [my bench press from 200 kg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=avAI7w4aQDU) to 220 kg.

one way I believe could work for me is instead of going heavy all the time, 
I am doing now 10 reps.

currently I can do 10 reps on 140 kg. 
I want to increase this to 10 reps of 160 kg.

Then I will start going heavy again.

Is there any system that supports this?

what are the possible (and proven) paths to increase the bench press for high reps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for something along the lines of [German Volume Training](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/luis13.htm) which has you working in 10x10, starting at 60% of your 1RM. Most GVT is linear in progression and so you miss out on the potential benefits of doing periodization.

Personally, based on your current level of lifting you would probably benefit from reading up on some of the more advanced (benching) programs written by coaches and picking one you like:

- [GZCL Method](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00GLX42U4)
- [5/3/1 by Jim Wedler](https://www.amazon.com/Jim-Wendler/e/B006P5V4RC/ref=pd_sim_351_bl_6?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B00DT5FIYQ&pd_rd_r=NV18J7WXK62MCR9CWVK3&pd_rd_w=lRdNn&pd_rd_wg=jmAt6&refRID=NV18J7WXK62MCR9CWVK3)
- [Sheiko Programs](http://sheiko-program.ru/training-programs/examples-of-programs)
- [Smolov Jr.](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fitness/comments/jdxdi/xpost_from_radvancedfitness_in_case_anyone_wanted/)

I would you really look at getting a personal lifting coach.

Comment: +1 thanks for the answer, could you explain a bit more on `"GVT is linear in progression and so you miss out on the potential benefits of doing periodization"`.

Comment: this answer was helpful to me gives me lots to consider.

Comment: German Volume Training (GVT) progresses you linearly so you add the same amount of weight each week you succeed your sets&reps. Most advanced programs use periodization: mixing up the number of reps and weight more to give you a good balance of different weight at different volumes. I suggest reading up on periodization as its too complex for a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it in progressive way. If you load the bar with any extra weight, than what your muscles are prepared for, that may cause injuries. I'd say go do a progression of 2.5 lbs for a couple of weeks. In a matter of 36 weeks you'd be able reach the goal of 45lbs which is 20 kgs. By that time your muscles would be stronger to handle the load. That's the safest way to do it. In this ego driven fitness industry, lifting heavy may matter, but staying safe matters more. After all, you don't want to hurt your shoulders or any other muscles and be out of training for months. Then start from ground zero. So, give yourself the time, and do it gradually. I'm not against heavy lifting, but I have seen people who bench 500 lbs, but they could barely play with their kids or do some daily normal activities without pain.

So follow the weekly approach and get ready for the heavy thing, and keep eating clean and give your muscles adequate rest time which is around 48-72 hours at the level you are, or which ever break suits you. Also, as Jj has suggested, going for a personal trainer would be ideal.

Comment: thank you for such wise words, unfortunately when you wrote them 4.5 years ago my ego and pride would not allow me to listen, you were very right!